# How do you get the return value of an async method?

Tags: .net, async-await

Hello I'm trying to understand the concept of task and async methods. I've been playing with this code for a while now to no avail.  Could someone please tell me how can I get the return value from the test() method and assign that value to a variable?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
   class Program
   {

    static  void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Task test1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => test());
        System.Console.WriteLine(test1);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static async Task<int> test()
    {
        Task t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {   Console.WriteLine("do stuff"); });
        await t;
        return 10;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Have a look at the articles on my [curah](http://curah.microsoft.com/45553/asyncawait-general "async-await General").

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the value out of a `Task` you can `await` the task which asynchronously waits for the task to complete and then returns the result. The other option is to call `Task.Result` which blocks the current thread until the result is available. This can cause a [deadlock](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) in GUI apps but is ok in console apps because they don't have a `SynchronizationContext`.

You can't use `await` in the `Main` method as it can't be `async` so one option is to use `test1.Result`:

```
static  void Main(string[] args)
{

    Task<int> test1 = Task.Factory.StartNew<int>(() => test());
    System.Console.WriteLine(test1.Result); // block and wait for the result
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

The other option is to create an `async` method that you call from `Main` and `await` the task inside it. You still may need to block waiting for the the `async` method to finish so you can call `Wait()` on the result of that method.

```
static  void Main(string[] args)
{
    MainAsync().Wait(); // wait for method to complete
    Console.ReadLine();
}

static async Task MainAsync()
{
    Task<int> test1 = Task.Factory.StartNew<int>(() => test());
    System.Console.WriteLine(await test1); 
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: Change `Task.Factory.StartNew` to `Task.Factory.StartNew<int>` for the tasks running `test()`. I updated my solution.

Comment: The error is because `Task` does not have a `Result` property but `Task<T>` does.

Comment: When dealing with `async-await`, use `Task.Run` instead of `Task.Factory.StartNew`.